# What would be the symbol for 'multiplication on division'?

Tags: symbols

The symbol I would like to obtain ought to be like the symbol '\pm'.

Comment: Is it by any chance that you need `\divideontimes` ?

Comment: Absolutely, Adam! That is what I need. 
Is this the code I ought to use?

Comment: Yes. If this is what you want I am placing it as an answer.

Comment: this actually does show up using [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org), so might be a candidate for duplicate: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)

Comment: There are some questions on Math.SE about what this symbol is for, maybe you could provide some explanation on what you needed it for? [older question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954186/what-is-the-symbol-divideontimes-divide-times-for) / [newer question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861245/%e2%8b%87-division-times-operator-in-unicode-u22c7)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The symbol you need to use is produced by the following command:

`\divideontimes`

Answer (score 3):

Here are some possibilities with the use of unicode (just as a demonstrative addition to Adam's answer). The Unicode for this symbol is [U+22C7](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22c7/index.htm).

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\setmainfont{code2000.ttf}\symbol{"22C7}\setmainfont{quivira.otf}\symbol{"22C7}\setmainfont{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"22C7}\\
    $\divideontimes$\setmathfont{XITS Math}$\divideontimes$\setmathfont{Asana Math}$\divideontimes$\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}$\divideontimes$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

PS: If you want to use one of the first-row symbols, you will have to wrap it in a `\mathrel{}` command.

Comment: To LaRiFaRi,
This is quite cool. I shall be so grateful to you for adding your knowledge to this matter. This may work perfectly. :)